# Setup http local server for downloading file

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode

I have some issues with bulk file downloads from a server. I tried downloading all files with NSURLSession downloadTask concurrently, lot of file downloads failed. I tried to download serially one after the other, then too some of them fail. After some research found that it is because of default value set to Keep Alive in the request header internally by iOS which is causing the issue.
I am trying to setup a local server and make some server config to check if there is some issue with server i am accessing. 
So any references or steps to install and configure(header parameters) a local server on mac high sierra which can be accessed from ios app.

Comment: flagging for removal, not a programming question

Comment: @il3v How is it not a programming question ? I am trying to debug an issue and trying to find ways to fix it

Answer (score 0):

MacOS ships with Apache already installed. All you need to do for a basic web server is start it up.

```
$ sudo apachectl start
```

This should then make a web server accessible at

```
http://localhost/
```